# base64_decode en wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, base64

Estoy intentado guardar un [html](/questions/tagged/html) codificado con [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) en la tabla `posts_meta` de **Wordpress** para luego obtener ese campo, decodificarlo y mostrar el contenido, pero de alguna manera se hace un "escape" de todas las comillas de manera que el Html tras ser descodificado se presenta así:

```
<div class=\"row\">
<div class=\"col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 column\">
</div>
```

Como lo puedo solucionar o que alternativas hay a la función base64_encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre procuro dar prioridad a los métodos o funciones nativas de **Wordpress** para evitar problemas a la larga.

Al final lo solucioné haciendo uso de la función:

> [wp_unslah()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unslash)

```
$html = '
<div class=\"row\">
<div class=\"col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 column\">
</div>';

$html = wp_unslash($html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar eso podrias eliminar el \ a traves de la funcion `str_replace()` por ejemplo;

```
$a = '<div class=\"col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 column\">';
$r = str_replace("\\","",$a);
```

o también podrías hacer uso de la función `stripslashes()` por ejemplo:

```
$a = '<div class=\"col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 column\">';
stripslashes($a)
```

para comprobar el funcionamiento de las mismas puedes imprimir el html como texto mediante `htmlspecialchars()`

```
echo htmlspecialchars($r);
echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($a));
```

En ambos casos te imprimirá: `<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 column">`